# Pandas - how to merge/join/concat two dataframes to have a tuple pairing of values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Lets say I have this as intput --

```py
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'grade' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 'score' : [9, 9, 8, 6]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['1', '2', '3', '4'] , 'id' : ['1', '2', '3', '4']})


df_1.head()
    grade   score
0   A       9
1   A       9
2   B       8
3   C       6
```

Then programmatically I want to achieve this --

```
    pair_1  pair_2
0   (1, A)  (1, 9)
1   (2, A)  (2, 9)
2   (3, B)  (3, 8)
3   (4, C)  (4, 6)
```

I realize the use case is a little weird, but I'd like to figure it out still.

*** EDIT ***

My original wording was misleading . Apologies for this . `df_2` is meant to have 2 unique columns. As per discussion with @Henry Ecker

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'grade' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 'score' : [9, 9, 8, 6]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['1', '2', '3', '4'] , 'key' : ['5', '6', '7', '8']})

   grade   score
0  (1, A)  (5, 9)
1  (2, A)  (6, 9)
2  (3, B)  (7, 8)
3  (4, C)  (8, 6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) is an option:

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'grade': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 'score': [9, 9, 8, 6]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'key': ['5', '6', '7', '8']})

# Zip Columns Together
for df_1k, df_2k in zip(df_1.columns, df_2.columns):
    # Map each group of columns into tuples
    df_1[df_1k] = list(map(tuple, zip(df_2[df_2k], df_1[df_1k])))

print(df_1)
```

`df_1`:

```
    grade   score
0  (1, A)  (5, 9)
1  (2, A)  (6, 9)
2  (3, B)  (7, 8)
3  (4, C)  (8, 6)
```

---

Directly into a new DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'grade': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 'score': [9, 9, 8, 6]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'key': ['5', '6', '7', '8']})

new_df = pd.DataFrame({
    df_1k: list(map(tuple, zip(df_2[df_2k], df_1[df_1k])))
    for df_1k, df_2k in zip(df_1.columns, df_2.columns)
})
print(new_df)
```

`new_df`

```
    grade   score
0  (1, A)  (5, 9)
1  (2, A)  (6, 9)
2  (3, B)  (7, 8)
3  (4, C)  (8, 6)
```

Comment: Hi Henry, my dummy code was a bit of a bad example. I meant to have unique columns for each dataframe. So just zipping on `df_2['id']` wont work for me

Comment: example below. I will also update question with same info

Comment: ```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'grade' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 'score' : [9, 9, 8, 6]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['1', '2', '3', '4'] , 'key' : ['5', '6', '7', '8']})

   grade   score
0  (1, A)  (5, 9)
1  (2, A)  (6, 9)
2  (3, B)  (7, 8)
3  (4, C)  (8, 6)
```